# TVF shows a Table Hint Error with no Table Hints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I rewrote a table valued function to use CTEs instead of table variables (Hopefully faster. Maybe not. I don't know. It doesn't run).  The TVF is created just fine, but when I run it, I get this error:

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

The original script has CTEs in it which don't cause this error, so I don't think it's that.  All I did was take out 4 table vars and turn them into CTEs on top of the already existing CTEs

I tried pulling out the select into parameter at the top, but I still get the error.

I don't see any table hint keywords, but I could be blind.

Any thoughts as to why the server is giving me this error?

Here is the code - sorry it's very extensive, but I don't want to remove the offending line by chopping it up.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tvfAT_CompareLastRL3]
(
    @county int
)
RETURNS @audittrail TABLE 
(
    id int
    ,StateLRS nchar(7)
    ,BMP decimal(12,3)
    ,EMP decimal(12,3)
    ,new_thru_mainttype nvarchar(255)
    ,new_thru_mainttype_ascii int
    ,new_thru_reptype       nvarchar(255)
    ,new_thru_reptype_ascii int
    ,new_thru_sor       nvarchar(255)
    ,new_thru_sor_ascii int
    ,new_thru_tot_width decimal(12,2)
    ,new_thru_lanes int
    ,old_thru_mainttype nvarchar(255)
    ,old_thru_mainttype_ascii int
    ,old_thru_reptype       nvarchar(255)
    ,old_thru_reptype_ascii int
    ,old_thru_sor       nvarchar(255)
    ,old_thru_sor_ascii int
    ,old_thru_tot_width decimal(12,2)
    ,old_thru_lanes int
    ,new_other_mainttype    nvarchar(255)
    ,new_other_mainttype_ascii int
    ,new_other_reptype      nvarchar(255)
    ,new_other_reptype_ascii    int
    ,new_other_sor      nvarchar(255)
    ,new_other_sor_ascii    int
    ,new_other_tot_width    decimal(12,2)
    ,new_other_lanes int
    ,old_other_mainttype    nvarchar(255)
    ,old_other_mainttype_ascii int
    ,old_other_reptype      nvarchar(255)
    ,old_other_reptype_ascii    int
    ,old_other_sor      nvarchar(255)
    ,old_other_sor_ascii    int
    ,old_other_tot_width    decimal(12,2)
    ,old_other_lanes int
    ,new_shld_mainttype nvarchar(255)
    ,new_shld_mainttype_ascii int
    ,new_shld_reptype       nvarchar(255)
    ,new_shld_reptype_ascii int
    ,new_shld_sor       nvarchar(255)
    ,new_shld_sor_ascii int
    ,new_shld_tot_width decimal(12,2)
    ,new_shld_lanes int
    ,old_shld_mainttype nvarchar(255)
    ,old_shld_mainttype_ascii int
    ,old_shld_reptype       nvarchar(255)
    ,old_shld_reptype_ascii int
    ,old_shld_sor       nvarchar(255)
    ,old_shld_sor_ascii int
    ,old_shld_tot_width decimal(12,2)
    ,old_shld_lanes int
    ,new_jur    nvarchar(255)
    ,new_jur_ascii  int
    ,new_ffc        nvarchar(255)
    ,new_ffc_ascii  int
    ,old_jur        nvarchar(255)
    ,old_jur_ascii  int
    ,old_ffc        nvarchar(255)
    ,old_ffc_ascii  int
    ,new_tot_adt    int
    ,old_tot_adt int
)
AS
BEGIN

declare @snap_year int--, @audit_year int
set @snap_year = (
    SELECT top 1 [year] from AuditYear where County = 23 and todate is not null order by [year] desc 
)

;with CteAll as(
        /* CLASS, ADT, THRU, OTHER, SHOULDER >>>>> DeMo */
    SELECT DISTINCT  substring(x.statelrs,1,2) CountyCode,  substring(x.statelrs,3,5) RoadNumber, x.StateLRS, x.BMP, x.EMP
    FROM DeMo..rlxthrulane_evw x
    join DeMo..tblclass_evw c on substring(c.jurisdiction,1,1) = '5' AND c.statelrs = x.statelrs and c.bmp < x.emp and c.emp > x.bmp
    WHERE 
    convert(int,substring(x.statelrs,1,2))=@county

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT  substring(x.statelrs,1,2) CountyCode,  substring(x.statelrs,3,5) RoadNumber, x.StateLRS, x.BMP, x.EMP
    FROM DeMo..rlxotherlane_evw x
    join DeMo..tblclass_evw c on substring(c.jurisdiction,1,1) = '5' AND c.statelrs = x.statelrs and c.bmp < x.emp and c.emp > x.bmp
    WHERE 
    convert(int,substring(x.statelrs,1,2))=@county

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT  substring(x.statelrs,1,2) CountyCode,  substring(x.statelrs,3,5) RoadNumber, x.StateLRS, x.BMP, x.EMP
    FROM DeMo..rlxshoulder_evw x
    join DeMo..tblclass_evw c on substring(c.jurisdiction,1,1) = '5' AND c.statelrs = x.statelrs and c.bmp < x.emp and c.emp > x.bmp
    WHERE 
    convert(int,substring(x.statelrs,1,2))=@county

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT CountyCode, RoadNumber, StateLRS, BMP, EMP
    FROM DeMo..tblclass_evw
    WHERE substring(Jurisdiction,1,2) = '5' AND
    countyCode=@county

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT substring(x.statelrs,1,2) CountyCode,  substring(x.statelrs,3,5) RoadNumber, x.StateLRS, x.BMP, x.EMP
    FROM DeMo..tbladt_evw x
    join DeMo..tblclass_evw c on substring(c.jurisdiction,1,1) = '5' AND c.statelrs = x.statelrs and c.bmp < x.emp and c.emp > x.bmp
    WHERE 
    convert(int,substring(x.statelrs,1,2))=@county

    UNION

    /* CLASS, ADT, THRU, OTHER, SHOULDER >>>>> MARS **using DeMar as surrogate */
    SELECT DISTINCT substring(x.statelrs,1,2) CountyCode,  substring(x.statelrs,3,5) RoadNumber, x.StateLRS, x.BMP, x.EMP
    FROM DeMar..snap_rlxthrulane x
        join DeMar..snap_tblclass c on substring(c.jurisdiction,1,1) = '5' AND c.statelrs = x.statelrs and c.bmp < x.emp and c.emp > x.bmp and c.AuditYear = @snap_year
    WHERE 
    convert(int,substring(x.statelrs,1,2))=@county and x.AuditYear = @snap_year

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT substring(x.statelrs,1,2) CountyCode,  substring(x.statelrs,3,5) RoadNumber, x.StateLRS, x.BMP, x.EMP
    FROM DeMar..snap_rlxotherlane x
        join DeMar..snap_tblclass c on substring(c.jurisdiction,1,1) = '5' AND c.statelrs = x.statelrs and c.bmp < x.emp and c.emp > x.bmp and c.AuditYear = @snap_year
    WHERE 
    convert(int,substring(x.statelrs,1,2))=@county and x.AuditYear = @snap_year

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT substring(x.statelrs,1,2) CountyCode,  substring(x.statelrs,3,5) RoadNumber, x.StateLRS, x.BMP, x.EMP
    FROM DeMar..snap_rlxshoulder x
        join DeMar..snap_tblclass c on substring(c.jurisdiction,1,1) = '5' AND c.statelrs = x.statelrs and c.bmp < x.emp and c.emp > x.bmp and c.AuditYear = @snap_year
    WHERE 
    convert(int,substring(x.statelrs,1,2))=@county and x.AuditYear = @snap_year

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT substring(statelrs,1,2) CountyCode,  substring(statelrs,3,5) RoadNumber, StateLRS, BMP, EMP
    FROM DeMar..snap_tblclass
    WHERE substring(jurisdiction,1,1) = '5' AND
    convert(int,substring(statelrs,1,2))=@county and AuditYear = @snap_year

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT substring(x.statelrs,1,2) CountyCode,  substring(x.statelrs,3,5) RoadNumber, x.StateLRS, x.BMP, x.EMP
    FROM DeMar..snap_tbladt x
        join DeMar..snap_tblclass c on substring(c.jurisdiction,1,1) = '5' AND c.statelrs = x.statelrs and c.bmp < x.emp and c.emp > x.bmp and c.AuditYear = @snap_year
    WHERE 
    convert(int,substring(x.statelrs,1,2))=@county and x.AuditYear = @snap_year
)
,Gaps as(
    --SELECT * FROM @ALL ORDER BY STATELRS,BMP
    /* FID GAPS AND CREATE ISLAND TO REMOVE */
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT StateLRS,
            MAX(EMP) OVER (PARTITION BY StateLRS ORDER BY BMP, EMP) AS GAP_START,
            LEAD(BMP, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY StateLRS ORDER BY BMP, EMP) AS GAP_END
        FROM CteAll
    ) a
    WHERE GAP_START < GAP_END
        --SELECT * FROM @GAPS ORDER BY STATELRS,BMP
)
,Temp as(
    SELECT StateLRS, BMP, EMP
    FROM (
        SELECT StateLRS, MP AS BMP, LEAD(MP, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY StateLRS ORDER BY MP) AS EMP
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT StateLRS, BMP AS MP
            FROM CteAll

            UNION

            SELECT DISTINCT StateLRS, EMP AS MP
            FROM CteAll
        ) a
    ) b
    WHERE EMP IS NOT NULL
)
,DynSeg as(
    --SELECT * FROM @TEMP ORDER BY STATELRS,BMP
        /* GENERATE SEGMENTS */
    SELECT tmp.StateLRS, tmp.BMP, tmp.EMP 
    FROM Temp tmp
        --LEFT JOIN @Gaps g ON g.StateLRS = tmp.StateLRS AND g.BMP = tmp.BMP AND g.EMP = tmp.EMP
        LEFT JOIN Gaps g ON g.StateLRS = tmp.StateLRS AND g.GAP_START = tmp.BMP AND g.GAP_END = tmp.EMP
    WHERE g.StateLRS IS NULL
    --ORDER BY StateLRS, BMP
)
,Segs as(
    --SELECT * FROM @DYNSEG ORDER BY STATELRS,BMP   
    /* RETRIEVE SEGMENT ATTRIBUTES */
    SELECT * FROM DynSeg
)
,NEW_THRU AS (
    select segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),',') MaintenanceType
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),',') ReplacementType
            ,checksum(string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by MaintenanceType )) MaintenanceTypeSum
            ,checksum(rType_xwalk) ReplacementTypeSum
            ,string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),',') SideOfRoad
            ,checksum(string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),'')) SideOfRoadSum
            ,sum(width) width 
            ,count(*) lanes
    from segs
    left join DeMo..rlxthrulane_evw tl on tl.StateLRS = segs.StateLRS and tl.BMP < segs.EMP and tl.EMP > segs.BMP
    outer apply(
        select string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by ReplacementType ) rType_xwalk
        from DeMo..rlxthrulane_evw tl
        where segs.StateLRS = tl.StateLRS and tl.BMP < segs.EMP and tl.EMP > segs.BMP
    ) rxwalk
    group by segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP,rType_xwalk
)
,OLD_THRU AS (
    select segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),',') MaintenanceType
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),',') ReplacementType
            ,checksum(string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by MaintenanceType )) MaintenanceTypeSum
            ,checksum(rType_xwalk) ReplacementTypeSum
            ,string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),',') SideOfRoad
            ,checksum(string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),'')) SideOfRoadSum
            ,sum(width) width 
            ,count(*) lanes
    from segs
    left join DeMar..snap_rlxthrulane tl on tl.StateLRS = segs.StateLRS and tl.BMP < segs.EMP and tl.EMP > segs.BMP and tl.AuditYear = @snap_year
    outer apply(
        select string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by ReplacementType ) rType_xwalk
        from DeMar..snap_rlxthrulane tl
        where segs.StateLRS = tl.StateLRS and tl.BMP < segs.EMP and tl.EMP > segs.BMP and tl.AuditYear = @snap_year
    ) rxwalk
    group by segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP,rType_xwalk
)
,NEW_OTHER AS (
    select segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),',') MaintenanceType
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),',') ReplacementType
            ,checksum(string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by MaintenanceType )) MaintenanceTypeSum
            ,checksum(rType_xwalk) ReplacementTypeSum
            ,string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),',') SideOfRoad
            ,checksum(string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),'')) SideOfRoadSum
            ,sum(width) width 
            ,count(*) lanes
    from segs
    left join DeMo..rlxotherlane_evw ol on ol.StateLRS = segs.StateLRS and ol.BMP < segs.EMP and ol.EMP > segs.BMP
    outer apply(
        select string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by ReplacementType ) rType_xwalk
        from DeMo..rlxotherlane_evw ol
        where segs.StateLRS = ol.StateLRS and ol.BMP < segs.EMP and ol.EMP > segs.BMP
    ) rxwalk
    group by segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP,rType_xwalk
)
,OLD_OTHER AS (
    select segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),',') MaintenanceType
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),',') ReplacementType
            ,checksum(string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by MaintenanceType )) MaintenanceTypeSum
            ,checksum(rType_xwalk) ReplacementTypeSum
            ,string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),',') SideOfRoad
            ,checksum(string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),'')) SideOfRoadSum
            ,sum(width) width 
            ,count(*) lanes
    from segs
    left join DeMar..snap_rlxotherlane ol on ol.StateLRS = segs.StateLRS and ol.BMP < segs.EMP and ol.EMP > segs.BMP and ol.AuditYear = @snap_year
    outer apply(
        select string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by ReplacementType ) rType_xwalk
        from DeMar..snap_rlxotherlane ol
        where segs.StateLRS = ol.StateLRS and ol.BMP < segs.EMP and ol.EMP > segs.BMP and ol.AuditYear = @snap_year
    ) rxwalk
    group by segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP,rType_xwalk
)
,NEW_SHLD AS (
    select segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),',') MaintenanceType
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),',') ReplacementType
            ,checksum(string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by MaintenanceType )) MaintenanceTypeSum
            ,checksum(rType_xwalk) ReplacementTypeSum
            ,string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),',') SideOfRoad
            ,checksum(string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),'')) SideOfRoadSum
            ,sum(width) width 
            ,count(*) lanes
    from segs
    left join DeMo..rlxshoulder_evw sh on sh.StateLRS = segs.StateLRS and sh.BMP < segs.EMP and sh.EMP > segs.BMP
    outer apply(
        select string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by ReplacementType ) rType_xwalk
        from DeMo..rlxshoulder_evw sh
        where segs.StateLRS = sh.StateLRS and sh.BMP < segs.EMP and sh.EMP > segs.BMP
    ) rxwalk
    group by segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP,rType_xwalk
)
,OLD_SHLD AS (
    select segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),',') MaintenanceType
            ,string_agg(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),',') ReplacementType
            ,checksum(string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(MaintenanceType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by MaintenanceType )) MaintenanceTypeSum
            ,checksum(rType_xwalk) ReplacementTypeSum
            ,string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),',') SideOfRoad
            ,checksum(string_agg(isnull(SideOfRoad,''),'')) SideOfRoadSum
            ,sum(width) width 
            ,count(*) lanes
    from segs
    left join DeMar..snap_rlxshoulder sh on sh.StateLRS = segs.StateLRS and sh.BMP < segs.EMP and sh.EMP > segs.BMP and sh.AuditYear = @snap_year
    outer apply(
        select string_agg(replace(isnull(substring(ReplacementType,1,3),''),'ACP','HMA'),'') within group( order by ReplacementType ) rType_xwalk
        from DeMar..snap_rlxshoulder sh
        where segs.StateLRS = sh.StateLRS and sh.BMP < segs.EMP and sh.EMP > segs.BMP and sh.AuditYear = @snap_year
    ) rxwalk
    group by segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP,rType_xwalk
)
,NEW_CLASS AS (
    select segs.statelrs, segs.bmp, segs.emp
        ,string_agg(isnull(substring(Jurisdiction,5,len(jurisdiction)-4),''), ',') Jurisdiction
        ,string_agg(isnull(substring(FunctionClass,1,2),''), ',') FFC
        ,checksum(string_agg(isnull(substring(Jurisdiction,5,len(Jurisdiction)-4),''),'') within group( order by Jurisdiction )) JurisdictionSum
        ,checksum(ffc_agg) FFCSum
        ,count(*) as NUM_AT_SEGMENT
    from segs
    left join DeMo..tblclass_evw tc on segs.statelrs = tc.statelrs and tc.bmp<segs.emp and tc.emp>segs.bmp
    outer apply(
        select string_agg(isnull(substring(FunctionClass,1,2),''),'') within group( order by FunctionClass) ffc_agg
        from DeMo..tblclass_evw tc
        where segs.statelrs = tc.statelrs and tc.bmp<segs.emp and tc.emp>segs.bmp
    ) agg
    group by segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP, ffc_agg
)
,OLD_CLASS AS (
    select segs.statelrs, segs.bmp, segs.emp
        ,string_agg(isnull(substring(Jurisdiction,5,len(jurisdiction)-4),''), ',') Jurisdiction
        ,string_agg(isnull(substring(FunctionClass,1,2),''), ',') FFC
        ,checksum(string_agg(isnull(substring(Jurisdiction,5,len(Jurisdiction)-4),''),'') within group( order by Jurisdiction )) JurisdictionSum
        ,checksum(ffc_agg) FFCSum
    from segs
    left join DeMar..snap_tblclass tc on segs.statelrs = tc.statelrs and tc.bmp<segs.emp and tc.emp>segs.bmp and tc.AuditYear = @snap_year
    outer apply(
        select string_agg( isnull(substring(FunctionClass,1,2),''),'') within group( order by FunctionClass) ffc_agg
        from DeMar..snap_tblclass tc
        where segs.statelrs = tc.statelrs and tc.bmp<segs.emp and tc.emp>segs.bmp and tc.AuditYear = @snap_year
    ) agg
    group by segs.StateLRS, segs.BMP, segs.EMP, ffc_agg
)
,NEW_ADT AS (
    SELECT segs.statelrs,segs.bmp,segs.emp
          ,ADTVolume ADT
          ,count(*) as NUM_AT_SEGMENT
    from segs 
    left join DeMo..tbladt_evw tl on segs.statelrs = tl.statelrs and tl.bmp<segs.emp and tl.emp>segs.bmp
    group by segs.statelrs,segs.bmp,segs.emp,ADTVolume
)
,OLD_ADT AS (
    SELECT segs.statelrs,segs.bmp,segs.emp
           ,ADTVolume ADT                       
    from segs 
    left join DeMar..snap_tbladt tl on segs.statelrs = tl.statelrs and tl.bmp<segs.emp and tl.emp>segs.bmp and tl.AuditYear = @snap_year
    --group by segs.statelrs,segs.bmp,segs.emp
)
        
insert into @audittrail
select row_number() over (order by nt.statelrs,ot.statelrs,nt.bmp,ot.bmp) id
    ,sgs.StateLRS,sgs.BMP,sgs.EMP
    ,nt.MaintenanceType new_thru_mainttype,nt.maintenancetypeSum new_thru_mainttype_ascii,nt.ReplacementTYpe new_thru_reptype,nt.ReplaceMentTypeSum new_thru_reptype_ascii,nt.sideofroad new_thru_sor,nt.SideOfRoadSum new_thru_sor_ascii,nt.width new_thru_tot_width,nt.lanes new_thru_lanes
    ,ot.MaintenanceType old_thru_mainttype,ot.maintenancetypeSum old_thru_mainttype_ascii,ot.ReplacementTYpe old_thru_reptype,ot.ReplaceMentTypeSum old_thru_reptype_ascii,ot.sideofroad old_thru_sor,ot.SideOfRoadSum old_thru_sor_ascii,ot.width old_thru_tot_width,ot.lanes old_thru_lanes
    ,[no].MaintenanceType new_other_mainttype,[no].maintenancetypeSum new_other_mainttype_ascii,[no].ReplacementTYpe new_other_reptype,[no].ReplaceMentTypeSum new_other_reptype_ascii,[no].sideofroad new_other_sor,[no].SideOfRoadSum new_other_sor_ascii,[no].width new_other_tot_width,[no].lanes new_other_lanes
    ,oo.MaintenanceType old_other_mainttype,oo.maintenancetypeSum old_other_mainttype_ascii,oo.ReplacementTYpe old_other_reptype,oo.ReplaceMentTypeSum old_other_reptype_ascii,oo.sideofroad old_other_sor,oo.SideOfRoadSum old_other_sor_ascii,oo.width old_other_tot_width,oo.lanes old_other_lanes
    ,ns.MaintenanceType new_shld_mainttype,ns.maintenancetypeSum new_shld_mainttype_ascii,ns.ReplacementTYpe new_shld_reptype,ns.ReplaceMentTypeSum new_shld_reptype_ascii,ns.sideofroad new_shld_sor,ns.SideOfRoadSum new_shld_sor_ascii,ns.width new_shld_tot_width,ns.lanes new_shld_lanes
    ,os.MaintenanceType old_shld_mainttype,os.maintenancetypeSum old_shld_mainttype_ascii,os.ReplacementTYpe old_shld_reptype,os.ReplaceMentTypeSum old_shld_reptype_ascii,os.sideofroad old_shld_sor,os.SideOfRoadSum old_shld_sor_ascii,os.width old_shld_tot_width,os.lanes old_shld_lanes
    ,nc.Jurisdiction new_jur,nc.JurisdictionSum new_jur_ascii,nc.FFC new_ffc,nc.FFCSum new_ffc_ascii
    ,oc.Jurisdiction old_jur,oc.JurisdictionSum old_jur_ascii,oc.FFC old_ffc,oc.FFCSum old_ffc_ascii
    ,na.ADT new_tot_adt
    ,oa.ADT old_tot_adt     
from (select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from new_thru
        union
        select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from old_thru
        union
        select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from new_other
        union
        select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from old_other
        union
        select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from new_shld
        union
        select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from old_shld
        union
        select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from new_class
        union
        select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from old_class
        union
        select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from new_adt
        union
        select statelrs,bmp,emp
        from old_adt
    ) sgs
    full outer join new_thru nt on nt.statelrs=sgs.statelrs and nt.bmp = sgs.bmp and nt.emp = sgs.emp
    full outer join old_thru ot on sgs.statelrs=ot.statelrs and sgs.bmp = ot.bmp and sgs.emp = ot.emp
    full outer join new_other [no] on [no].statelrs = sgs.statelrs and [no].bmp = sgs.bmp and [no].emp = sgs.emp
    full outer join old_other oo on oo.statelrs = sgs.statelrs and oo.bmp = sgs.bmp and oo.emp = sgs.emp
    full outer join new_shld ns on ns.statelrs = sgs.statelrs and ns.bmp = sgs.bmp and ns.emp = sgs.emp
    full outer join old_shld os on os.statelrs = sgs.statelrs and os.bmp = sgs.bmp and os.emp = sgs.emp
    full outer join new_class nc on nc.statelrs = sgs.statelrs and nc.bmp = sgs.bmp and nc.emp = sgs.emp
    full outer join old_class oc on oc.statelrs = sgs.statelrs and oc.bmp = sgs.bmp and oc.emp = sgs.emp
    full outer join new_adt na on na.statelrs = sgs.statelrs and na.bmp = sgs.bmp and na.emp = sgs.emp
    full outer join old_adt oa on oa.statelrs = sgs.statelrs and oa.bmp = sgs.bmp and oa.emp = sgs.emp
where               
    -- PRESENT COUNTY JUR W/INCOMPLETE
    (
        --PRESENTLY COUNTY
        (nc.Jurisdiction='County' OR nc.NUM_AT_SEGMENT>1)
                    
        AND 

        --MISSING MVFT CONTROL VALUE
        (
            nc.NUM_AT_SEGMENT>1
            OR          
            na.NUM_AT_SEGMENT>1
            OR
            isnull(nt.maintenancetypeSum,0)=0 
            OR 
            isnull(nt.ReplacementTypeSum,0)=0
            OR
            isnull(nt.width ,0)<=0
            OR
            isnull(nc.ffcsum ,0)=0
            OR
            --na.adt is null
            isnull(na.adt,0)<=0
        )
    )
                
    OR
                
    -- PAST/PRESENT COUNTY JUR WITH CHANGE DETECTED
    (
        (nc.jurisdiction='County' OR oc.Jurisdiction='County')
        -- CHECK THAT MVFT CHANGE OCCURRED IN ANY COMBINATION USING ORs
        AND
        (
            isnull(nt.maintenancetypeSum,0)<>isnull(ot.MaintenanceTypeSum ,0)
            OR isnull(nt.ReplacementTypeSum,0)<>isnull(ot.ReplacementTypeSum  ,0)
            --OR isnull(nt.SideOfRoadSum ,0)<>isnull(ot.SideOfRoadSum  ,0)
            OR isnull(nt.width ,0) <> isnull(ot.width  ,0)
            --OR isnull(nt.lanes ,0) <> isnull(ot.lanes ,0)
            OR isnull([no].maintenancetypeSum ,0)<>isnull(oo.MaintenanceTypeSum  ,0)
            OR isnull([no].ReplacementTypeSum ,0)<>isnull(oo.ReplacementTypeSum  ,0)
            --OR isnull([no].SideOfRoadSum ,0)<>isnull(oo.SideOfRoadSum  ,0)
            OR isnull([no].width ,0) <> isnull(oo.width  ,0)
            --OR isnull([no].lanes ,0) <> isnull(oo.lanes ,0)
            OR isnull(ns.maintenancetypeSum ,0)<>isnull(os.MaintenanceTypeSum  ,0)
            OR isnull(ns.ReplacementTypeSum ,0)<>isnull(os.ReplacementTypeSum  ,0)
            --OR isnull(ns.SideOfRoadSum ,0)<>isnull(os.SideOfRoadSum  ,0)
            OR isnull(ns.width ,0) <> isnull(os.width ,0) 
            --OR isnull(ns.lanes ,0) <> isnull(os.lanes ,0)
            OR isnull(nc.jurisdictionsum,0)<>isnull(oc.jurisdictionsum,0)
            OR isnull(nc.ffcsum ,0)<>isnull(oc.ffcsum  ,0)
                        
            --ADT CHANGE DETEECTION w\ (+/- 5000 rule)
            OR (
                    --T
                    isnull(na.adt ,0)<>isnull(oa.adt ,0) 
                AND             
                    (
                        ---- ONLY MUST BE NULL, BOTH NULL WOULD FAIL <> CHECK ABOVE
                        --T
                        na.adt is null OR oa.adt is null
                        OR
                        (
                            -- check not both over 5k or under 5k
                            NOT(isnull(na.adt,0)>5000 AND isnull(oa.adt,0)>5000) 
                                AND
                            NOT(isnull(na.adt,0)<5000 AND isnull(oa.adt,0)<5000)
                        )
                    )
                ) -- END_ADT CHANGE DETECTION
        ) -- END_AND                
    ) -- END PAST/PRESENT W/MVFT CHANGE DETECTED
            
    order by sgs.statelrs,sgs.bmp
RETURN 
END
GO
```

Comment: Honestly, I think you're trying to do to much in a simple function. I'd convert it to a stored procedure where you have a lot more options.

Comment: And CTE's are frequently **not faster** because you get a single, very complex, query plan. As soon as you split the query out into temp tables, or table variables, you allow SQL Server to generate multiple, smaller, simpler, query plans, which frequently perform better.

Comment: CTE's are not performance constructs, they just allow you to simplify some forms of sub-query from a usability perspective.

Comment: Note, the `;` (semi-colon) is a statement *terminator* and should terminate every statement. Its not a *begininator*.

Comment: And all those coverts in your where clauses will kill performance, since that makes the query unsargeable (unable to use indexes). You want to avoid any kind of function in your where clauses.

Comment: Also use UNION ALL instead of UNION if you want all the rows from both queries.  UNION = UNION ALL + DISTINCT.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK  I will keep all this in mind.  Unfortunately, for this particular instance, my hands are tied for much of it.  It must be a tvf and not a stored procedure, as it is part of select statement of a different stored procedure.   The semi-colon separates the set from the CTE beginning (we just generally put them at the beginning, since CTEs often require them do to other statement above them)  Because it's a tvf, I can't use temp tables (which would have been my preference and I tried initially).  So, I'm kind of stuck at Why does TSQL see a table hint where there isn't one.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft.  We definitely want the UNION and not the UNION ALL.  The "+ Distinct" is a nice safety net in our case.

Comment: `UNION` is frequently **much** slower than `UNION ALL` - you are often better off handling duplicates yourself.

Comment: I understand why you use the `;` as you are, I'm just pointing out that its not correct as per Microsofts guidelines.

Comment: My question then is, why are you re-writing it? If you are trying to speed it up, and are failing, then leave it as it is. And if there is an issue, raise it with your lead that the structure has to change. Some problems can't be solved with the existing constraints.

Comment: My guess is that the shear complexity of your function (it is very very complex), is causing SQL Server to fail to be able to generate an execution plan - that really is a thing. Why its returning you that error I don't know. But I think the lesson is, find a way to simplify the queries

Comment: You can use table variables in a function, so go back to doing that, rather than building a mammoth query.

Comment: Also I see you are doing `insert into @tableName...` its best practice to list the columns you are inserting into. Will save you pain later.